# Is it right to call a chapter of a book an "appendix"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context, vocabulary, books

In *Think Python, 2nd Edition* the author states at the beginning of *Chapter 21. Analysis of Algorithms*: **"This appendix is an edited excerpt from ink Complexity, by Allen B. Downey, also published by O’Reilly Media (2012). When you are done with this book, you might want to move on to that one."**

The online version of *Cambridge Dictionary* defines *"appendix"* as **"a separate part at the end of a book or magazine that gives extra information."**

So I think that this chapter is a part of the the book, and not *"separate"* from it, but I may be getting something wrong. So, Is the author right or wrong? Why and why not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: An appendix is something that has been appended.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of an appendix, as given by a few other sources is:

> Dictionary.com: supplementary material at the end of a book, article,
>   document, **or other text, usually of an explanatory, statistical, or
>   bibliographic nature.**
>
> Merriam-Webster: supplementary material **usually** attached at the
>   end of a piece of writing
>
> [Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/appendix.html): Supplementary document, forming a part of a main document but not essential for its completeness, containing supporting information and appearing usually at the end.

As previously mentioned, appendix comes from append, which means to add as a supplement or accessory.

It is indeed most common for an appendix to come at the end of a book.  And as you said, some dictionaries specifically state that the appendix comes at the end. But it is not necessary for the appendix to be last.  It is just a very widely held convention, as it often makes the most logical sense.

Putting the appendix last has come to be such a widely held convention that it has become a part of the definition of the word.  But originally, the idea was the appendix is a list of appended information meant to supplement the main work.  And therefore would not *necessarily* need to come at the end of a work.

If this author simply edited and shortened another work but fully intended for every reader to read the information, then calling it an appendix would be inaccurate. [By the very nature of an appendix, it should contain additional, non-vital information to supplement the main work.  But it should not be required or expected reading.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Professional_and_Technical_Writing/Design/Back_Matter)  Also refer back to the Business Dictionary definition.  This is the very reason why an appendix is almost always found at the end of a work.

So I would say the answer to your question depends on the nature of information included in the appendix.  If the information included is supplementary in nature and non-essential, then it could still be called an appendix (although possibly a poorly placed one).  But if the information is merely appended but still required, then it is not an appendix, per se, but could more properly be described as some appended information from another source.

Comment: Thank you! It happens that this chapter is the last one. I'm asking whether it's right to call this chapter an appendix, because I consider a chapter a coherent part of a book, not just a *supplementary material*, that may be skipped, IMHO. What do you think?

Comment: I see your dilemma.  To give it a chapter title is quite out of the ordinary.  But I would maintain, especially because it is the last chapter, that it could still be considered an appendix.  As long as the information was supplementary.  But as you said, it doesn't feel very supplementary to give the appendix a chapter.  And as I previously said myself, it could just be a very poorly placed appendix, while still serving the purpose of an appendix.  --- Long story short, I would say it could still be considered an appendix, but that it was perhaps not a good choice by the author.